# Port forwad public ip port to internal server on different interface

Tags: iptables, nat, port-forwarding, forwarding

Hello I am trying to port forward a public ip:port I have on a wan interface to a server on my lan

my server has two interfaces

- ens19 [WAN]
- ens18 [LAN]

I then have another server connected on the same LAN.

I am trying to forward that wan ip:port to my second servers lan ip:port

I have tried the following commands

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface ens18 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface ens19 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i ens19 -m tcp --dport 1522 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.74.72.52:22
```

when I then try and ssh my wanip:1522 the connection times out

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default           203.0.113.1  0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens19
localnet        *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens18
  203.0.113.92  *               255.255.255.224 U         0 0          0 ens19
```

I have enabled ipv4 forwarding in systemctl

Answer (score 0):

Use `tcpdump` to watch the traffic on the interfaces on the router and on the receiving server.

Make sure that the default route of the receiving server points to the router.

You do MASQUERADE for output interface ens18 (LAN) and allow everything in on ens19 (WAN). Did you switch the descriptions of the interfaces? On the other hand, the incoming requests would come from the WAN, so there ens19 as WAN would be correct.

Comment: I think the default route is the missing piece, i added routing table to orignal question

Comment: I can see the packets in tcp dump hitting the ens19 but doesnt give any indication of error, simultaneous tcp dump on ens18 doesnt show any activity

Comment: Look at the counters in `iptables -vnL` and `iptable -t nat -vnL`. The counters should increase when you try to connect. If you have blocking rules (DROP or REJECT), add a LOG rule before them. Add an ACCEPT rule for incoming port 1522 packets. The default route refers to 10.74.72.52, it must point to the router.

Comment: the default route links to the public wan gateway, this is a different gateway to our lan